# Use facebook data to register on XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to use facebook login to register the user in XMPP personal server. Also is possible to login with user and pass to the server. So, how must I register the facebook user on the xmpp server? Which data should I use?

I can use facebook e-mail as login and user id as password, but this data is available for most people and another user can be login with this data with the traditional form. Other option is use the access token, but it changes between sessions.

The Facebook API gives the possibility to know on the device who is the user with out hacking, but, how can I be sure that he is the user on the XMPP server?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please read the **authentication** section of the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Also there will be some good info relating to **android** here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/

You may also be interested in using Facebook's **Chat API**.  Check it out to see if it would be a good fit for your app.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/